# Java/JNI - Is it OK to return a jstring as a jobject directly to java?

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I have a [SANE](https://sane-project.gitlab.io/standard/api.html) binding with Java throught JNI and I experience crashes when touching the funcion:

Java Side

```
native Object nativeGetCurrentValue(long hnd, int num, int type);
```

Native Side

```
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_package_Sane_nativeGetCurrentValue(JNIEnv * env, jobject o, jlong hnd, jint num, jint type) {
    void *value;


    if (sane_control_option((SANE_Handle *) hnd, num, SANE_ACTION_GET_VALUE, value, NULL) == SANE_STATUS_GOOD) {
        switch (type) {
            case SANE_TYPE_BOOL: {
//                fprintf(stderr, "SANE_TYPE_BOOL...\n");
                jboolean * v = (jboolean *)value;

                jclass cls = env->FindClass("java/lang/Boolean");
                jmethodID midBool = env->GetMethodID(cls, "<init>", "(Z)V");
                return env->NewObject(cls, midBool, *v);
            }
            case SANE_TYPE_FIXED: {
//                fprintf(stderr, "SANE_TYPE_FIXED...\n");
                SANE_Word * v = (SANE_Word *)value;
                double d = SANE_UNFIX(*v);

                jclass cls = env->FindClass("java/lang/Double");
                jmethodID midDoub = env->GetMethodID(cls, "<init>", "(D)V");
                return env->NewObject(cls, midDoub, (jdouble)d);
            }
            case SANE_TYPE_INT: {
//                fprintf(stderr, "SANE_TYPE_INT...\n");
                int * v = (int *)value;

                jclass cls = env->FindClass("java/lang/Integer");
                jmethodID midInit = env->GetMethodID(cls, "<init>", "(I)V");
                return env->NewObject(cls, midInit, *v);
            }
            case SANE_TYPE_STRING:
//                fprintf(stderr, "SANE_TYPE_STRING...\n");
                jstring str = env->NewStringUTF((char *)value);
                return str;
        }
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

I suspect I'm doing something wrong.

Is it ok to return a jstring created with `env->NewStringUTF` to java?

Comment: Returning a `jstring` should be fine. Could try with `-Xcheck:jni`.

Comment: The documentation for `sane_control_option` says "It is a pointer to the memory that holds the option value. The memory area pointed to by v must be big enough to hold the entire option value (determined by member size in the corresponding option descriptor).". Does your actual code allocate memory for `value`?

Comment: @Botje you're right, I've missed that. Will test it, but that's probably the cause.